# On item hover wait 3 seconds then fadeTo 0.2 all of items exept this

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I need to make this happen:

On item hover wait 3 seconds then `fadeTo(0.2`) all items except `this` (the hovered one)
and 
on mouse leave `fadeTo(1)` all items.

I placed my the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/f7DJa/
but it's without the 3 second waiting and also not really working smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var items = $('.item', '.loop'); //find all items within loop

items.on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        items.not(this).stop(true, true).delay(3000).fadeTo('slow', 0.2);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        items.not(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f7DJa/9/)

Or just for fun:

```
var items = $('.item', '.loop');
items.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var state = e.originalEvent.type==='mouseout'?false:true;
    items.not(this).stop(true, true).delay(state?3000:0).fadeTo('slow', state?0.2:1);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f7DJa/11/)

Comment: 1 question, why do you need `.loop` in items? If I understood correctly, Just `var items = $('.item')` should work fine.

Comment: Yes it should, unless there are other elements on the page with the class "item", it's a common word so I just narrowed it down to all elements with that class inside the "loop" class, but it's not needed if the OP is certain there are no other elements that can be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var timer = null;
$('.item').hover(function() {
    var $el = $(this).siblings();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $el.stop(true, true).fadeTo('fast', 0.2);
    }, 3000);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(".item").stop(true, true).fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7DJa/6/)

The three second wait seems an odd requirement. Most users won't wait around to hover the mouse over an element for 3 seconds - especially not without some clue that something will happen if they do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code this achieve this

```
$('.item').hover(function(){
                $('.item').stop(true,true).not(this).delay(3000).fadeTo('fast',0.5)

         }, function(){ 
                $('.item').stop(true,true).fadeTo('slow', 1);
         });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/f7DJa/8/)